# Informatica Session getting failed due to error GPWRT_34014

Tags: error-handling, informatica, informatica-powercenter, greenplum

2017-02-06 12:26:23 : ERROR : (16120 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | INF_PW1_ASCII) : NODE_PWDEV_PWNLD1022v04 : GPWRT_34014 : [ERROR] The Integration Service failed to create a pipe because of insufficient memory allocation or because it does not have required permissions to the directory specified for the pipe location in the session.

2017-02-06 12:26:23 : ERROR : (16120 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | INF_PW1_ASCII) : NODE_PWDEV_PWNLD1022v04 : SDKS_38502 : Plug-in #431050's target [ods_ap_invoices_all: Partition 1] failed in method [init].

2017-02-06 12:26:23 : ERROR : (16120 | WRITER_1_*_1) : (IS | INF_PW1_ASCII) : NODE_PWDEV_PWNLD1022v04 : WRT_8068 : Writer initialization failed. Writer terminating.

Comment: Not an error messahe I'm familiar with, have you checked the write permissions in the target directory where you're trying to create the file?

Comment: Does the error occur every time you run the session?

Comment: Can you make the error go away by changing the target type to 'flat file' and/or the target directory to something else

Comment: Daniel, write permission is there in tgt dir. Thanks.

Comment: Olsen, yes, your way worked... tested with flat_file...